# How to count the number of adjacent pairs in a list?

Tags: combinatorics

Say you have a gun with six chambers, and someone puts two bullets in adjacent slots.  How do you count the number of pairs of slots that exist?  I can figure this out by enumerating each one, but how do you do it in the general case.  For N choose K (but where K is contiguous)

Comment: If we have the $N$ slots in a circle, and $K\lt N$, there are $N$ ways to place $K$ "bullets" so that they are all adjacent. But it is not clear what it is precisely that you need to count.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is equal to $N$ where $N$ is the number of slots. For any slot $x$, $x$ and the slot next to it in the clockwise direction form an adjacent pair (and every adjacent pair is of this sort). A similar argument works for $K$ adjacent slots when $N>K > 2$. Of course this only holds for a circular arrangement of slots.